# Trying to better understand switch statements and how their expressions are related/tests

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm reading through my C textbook and I'm completely stumped on any attempt to understand the following code fragment. The book doesn't give a complete program and only states that the variable angle is a double, and angletype is an int which will somehow determine which case to use? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
switch (angletype)
{
 case DEG:
  angle *= PI / 180.0; /* convert to radians */
  /* fall through */
 case RAD:
  while (angle > PI) /* normalise radians */
   angle -= 2.0*PI;
  while (angle < -PI)
   angle += 2.0*PI;
  break;
 default:
  printf("Error: Invalid type\n");
  break;
}
```

EDIT: Here is what I have done so far with the fragment:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define DEG
#define RAD
#define PI 3.14


void main()
{

int angletype;
double angle;

switch (angletype)
{
 case DEG:
 angle *= PI / 180.0; /* convert to radians */
 /* fall through */
 case RAD:
  while (angle > PI) /* normalise radians */
  angle -= 2.0*PI;
  while (angle < -PI)
  angle += 2.0*PI;
 break;
 default:
 printf("Error: Invalid type\n");
 break;
}

}
```

I'm just having trouble coming up with some working prototype. I'm not sure how the expression "(angletype)" and the cases DEG and RAD will interact.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking, and you did not provide a [MCVE].

Comment: `#define DEG` `#define RAD` What do these do on their own? Where are your variables given values?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The book only states they are symbolic constants, which is not very useful. It gives no further context. I'm trying to think up a working prototype to better understand the example.

Answer (score 2):

A `switch` statement uses an integral expression as its control, and each `case` label is also an integral expression:

```
switch( some_integer )
{
  case 1: // do something if some_integer == 1
    break;

  case 2: // do something else if some_integer == 2
    break;

  case 3: // do some completely different thing if some_integer == 3
    break;
  ...

  default: // do something else if some_integer isn't a value covered by
           // any of the previous cases
}
```

Think of a `switch` as a computed GOTO, and each `case` label as one of the possible values.

For this particular snippet, `DEG` and `RAD` are symbolic constants for some integer value, probably defined as

```
#define DEG 0
#define RAD 1
```

or similar.

This particular code snippet is doing an angular calculation using radians, so it checks the angle type first to see if it needs to be converted from degrees to radians.  If `angletype` is `DEG`, it branches to `case DEG:` to perform the conversion before doing the calculation.  If `angletype` is `RAD`, it branches to `case RAD:` to perform the calculation.  If `angletype` is any other value, it branches to `default` and prints an error message.

Answer (score 1):

> The book doesn't give a complete program and only states that the variable angle is a double, and angletype is an int which will somehow determine which case to use?

It looks like `angletype` is probably an enumeration, like:

```
typedef enum {
    DEG,
    RAD
} AngleType;

AngleType angleType;
```

Somewhere in the code preceding the `switch`, the value of `angletype` has to be set to one of the values. (An enumeration isn't the only way to go... `DEG` and `RAD` could of course be `#define`s, but any way you slice it `DEG` and `RAD` have some set values known at compile time, and `angletype` is variable.

In the case where `angletype` is `DEG`, then the `switch` jumps to the `DEG` case:

```
 case DEG:
    angle *= PI / 180.0; /* convert to radians */
    /* fall through */
 case RAD:
     while (angle > PI) /* normalise radians */
 //...
```

First line in the body of the `DEG` case converts `angle` to radians by multiplying it by π/180 (because there are 180° in π radians). Once `angle` is converted to radians, then it makes sense to continue on with the `RAD` case for whatever additional work is needed. Notice that there's no `break` statement at the end of the `DEG` case... that means that execution doesn't stop there, it just keeps going on into the `RAD` case.

Answer (score 1):

Your `switch` statement is equivalent to the [much clearer] following:

```
if (angletype == DEG)
{
   // Convert to radians
   angle *= PI / 180.0;
   angletype = RAD;
}

if (angletype == RAD)
{
   // Normalise radians
   while (angle > PI)
      angle -= 2.0 * PI;

   while (angle < -PI)
      angle += 2.0 * PI;
}
else
{
   printf("Error: Invalid type\n");
}
```

In other words, *just a load of straightforward conditions*. Nothing magic here.

Presumably, `DEG` and `RAD` name enums or some other integral value. And, presumably, `angletype` is set to one of them somewhere.

You can read more about `switch` in your C book.